# JavaScript | TypeError: Не удается обнаружить функцию replace в объекте

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

У меня есть такой код

```
/*valuesRow[0] = modelnumber; valuesRow[1] = spec 1; valuesRow[2] = spec 2; 
valuesRow[3] = spec 3*/

var modelnumber = valuesRow[0].replace(/\s+/g, '');
var spec1 = valuesRow[1].replace(/\s+/g, '');
var spec2 = valuesRow[2].replace(/\s+/g, '');
var spec3 = valuesRow[3].replace(/\s+/g, '');
var spec4 = valuesRow[4].replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Но я получаю ошибку `Не удается обнаружить функцию replace в объекте 231132`

231132 - данная , с массива.

Как мне правильно сделать, чтобы убирало пробелы если они есть, а если нету - просто игнорировало.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `toString().replace(...`  предварительно valuesRow[] оберните в скобки. Получится так: `(valuesRow[*]).toString().replace(/\s+/g, '');`

Comment: Спасибо большое , помогли!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `toString().replace(...` 
предварительно `valuesRow[]` оберните в скобки. Получится так: 
`(valuesRow[*]).toString().replace(/\s+/g, '');`